# Вопрос по json php + foreach

Tags: php, json, foreach

Суть проблемы такова, делаю вывод логинов по поисковому запросу:

```
$response = array();

$searchStr = htmlspecialchars(urldecode(iconv('UTF-8', 'windows-1251', urldecode($project['text']))));

$base = $db->rows("SELECT `login` FROM `base` WHERE LOWER(login) LIKE LOWER('%{$searchStr}%') AND `uid` = ".$_SESSION['id']." AND `delete` = '0' ORDER BY `id` LIMIT 10");

if($searchStr != ''):

    foreach ($base as $key => $search):

        $text[$key][] = $search['login'];

    endforeach;

    foreach ($text as $akk):

        if(strpos($akk, $searchStr) !== false):

            $response[] = $akk;

        endif;

    endforeach;

endif;

die(json_encode($response));
```

В результате я получаю при запросе с текстом mya = [["MyAkk1"],["MyAkk2"],["MyAkk3"]], как сделать так, чтобы выводило ["MyAkk1","MyAkk2","MyAkk3"]

Answer (score 2):

```
foreach ($base as $key => $search):
        $text[$key][] = $search['login'];
    endforeach;
```

изменить на

```
 foreach ($base as $key => $search):
        $text[] = $search['login'];
    endforeach;
```

или ввести промежуточный массив если необходима именно такая структура

Answer (score 0):

Попробуйте в строке `$response[] = $akk;` поменять, чтобы было `$response = $akk;`